# Django Serializer - Create object with relations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create and App object through the Django REST Framework. I am using a nested Version object and relate this to a already existing client.

This is the model that I have, so you could get a better idea:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)


class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='client_keywords',on_delete=models.CASCADE)  

class App(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='client_apps', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Version(models.Model):
    apps = models.ForeignKey(App, related_name='version',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

As you can see Clients can have multiples Apps(1->N), and Apps can have multiple versions (1 -> N)

I've implemented the following serializer so I can create the App object with the necessari relations but I must be doing something wrong:

```
class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version = VersionSerializer(many=True)
    client = ClientSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = App
        fields = ('pk','client',..., 'version')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        versions_data = validated_data.pop('version')
        clients_data = validated_data.pop('client')
        app = App.objects.create(**validated_data)
        app.client = Client.objects.get(pk=clients_data['client'])
        for version_data in versions_data:
            Version.objects.create(apps=app, **version_data)
        return app
```

My idea here is to get the pk from "clients_data['client']" which i'm sending in the POST, get the client object for that PK and assign it for this new app, and after that create the required versions.

But after a lot of tests the client_id in the database continuous empty. How can I assign the client correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

If it helps to someone else, you need to pass the client object to the app when you create it!

```
class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version = VersionSerializer(many=True)
    client = ClientSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = App
        fields = ('pk','client',..., 'version')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        versions_data = validated_data.pop('version')
        clients_data = validated_data.pop('client')
        clients_info = Client.objects.get(pk=clients_data['client'])
        app = App.objects.create(client=clients_info,**validated_data)

        for version_data in versions_data:
            Version.objects.create(apps=app, **version_data)
        return app
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Model
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)

# View

from rest_framework import generics,viewsets
from api.models import Album
from api.serializers import AlbumSerializer


class TracksView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

class TracksView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

# serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Album

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].